# timezone conversion in php

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar

My defaulst timezone in google calendar is (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time. Now i generate a meeting request and invite two persons. 
1) one person whose default timezone in his calendar is (GMT+05:30) Pacific Time and his email are coming through microsoft exchange server.
2) second i invite a person on gmail account who is having default timezone as (GMT+05:30). 
 the ics file which i view has DTSTART as DTSTART:20110506T170000Z it just means like
 yyyymmdd T hhmmss so here time comes proper in gmail. 
 but the first person viewing microsoft gets DTSTART:20110506T070000Z so here my question is how to convert timezone so that both comes the same...

```
date_default_timezone_set($timezonename[0]->timzone_val); 
$meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date." ".$timezonename[0]->timzone_val);
$dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\This\Z",$meetingstamp);
$dtend= gmdate("Ymd\This\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
$todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\This\Z");
```

here my timzone comes as America/Los_Angeles so how which function shall i use to get proper timings...????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start = new DateTime($meeting_date, new DateTimeZone($timezonename[0]->timzone_val);
$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end   = clone $start;
$end->modify(sprintf('+ %d seconds', $meeting_duration));

echo $start->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
echo $end->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
```

*It should be an upper-case `H` in the date formatting string by the way, beacuse lower-case `h` represents ours in 12-hout-format.*

**EDIT** after last comment

```
$start = new DateTime('2011-05-07 10:00', new DateTimeZone('PDT'));
$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end   = clone $start;
$end->modify(sprintf('+ %d seconds', 1*60*60));

echo $start->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
echo "\n";
echo $end->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
```

results in

```
20110507T170000Z
20110507T180000Z
```

That are exactly the values you'd like to get.

Comment: in my server datetime class is not enabled i think, i am using php 5.3.1 so from where can i check that it is enable or disabled.

Comment: `DateTime` is available in PHP 5.2.0 and later and it cannot be disabled (as far as I know) at all. So if you're using 5.3.1 you should be safe using the `DateTime` classes.

Comment: still the same i am getting...  20110507T070000Z
20110507T080000Z

Comment: Can you add a clear example (including the start of the meeting, the duration and the timezone)?

Comment: @stefan: start time 10:00 am end time 11:00 AM timezone is PDT (GMT -8:00) now if i chk the source in gmail with it comes as DTSTART:20110507T170000Z
DTEND:20110507T180000Z but in my script it comes as 20110507T070000Z 20110507T080000Z